# Blank page in Stardog's database web interface

Tags: rdf, ontology, triplestore, stardog

Whenever I create a new database from Stardog's web interface like this :

[image]

I'm facing a blank page at `http://localhost:5820/#/databases/cool`.
But `http://localhost:5820/#/databases/cool/edit` works perfectly.

**How to reproduce this bug**

1. Got Stardog 2.2 installed before this, with existing data in `/data/stardog`
2. `stardog-admin server stop`
3. `rm -rf /data/stardog`
4. Downloaded Stardog 2.2.1, extracted zip file
5. Launched `stardog-admin server start` without any error
6. Accessing `localhost:5820` without any problem then creating my db

Encountered the same problem with `server-admin db create -n cool`

Comment: It seems like this question would be better asked on the official Stardog mailing list - https://groups.google.com/a/clarkparsia.com/forum/#!forum/stardog

Comment: The URLs for the db homepage you mention are exactly the same, so it's not clear what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, post corrected.

Comment: Are you missing a step, what you've described worked ok for me